# Problems installing 12.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, uefi

I have a Lenovo Y400 notebook, and I hate Windows 8.  So, I tried to install and dual-boot Ubuntu.  I immediately ran into problems.

First of all, 13.10 won't boot. Unfortunately, I haven't tried it for a while, so I don't know the details, but I remember that I immediately switched to 12.04 x64.
I then tried installing Ubuntu using the standard installer in EFI mode, with SecureBoot off. It worked, and GRUB showed up in my boot-devices list.

However, the only option that worked was Ubuntu recovery -- Standard Ubuntu and Win8 just gave me an orange-brown screen.  I tried `nomodeset` which gave me a working command prompt, but `sudo service gdm start` didn't do anything, and I'm not l33t enough to do everything from a command line.  So, I tried a few assorted tricks, including booting from a live CD in both EFI and Legacy.  I can't use boot-repair as I can't connect to WiFi -- I will try it when I get hold of an Ethernet cable.  Ubuntu recovery worked fine, but didn't get me anywhere.

After some tinkering, I realized that GRUB was gone from my UEFI's list of boot devices.  It had occasionally disappeared before, right after I switched from Legacy to UEFI, but now it's gone and doesn't want to come back.

I know similar posts have been made -- none of the solutions proposed got me anywhere.  Anything else I can try?

I managed to run boot-repair from the LiveCD.  It failed, giving http://paste.ubuntu.com/6019512 and saying that I should retry after creating a `/boot/efi` partition.  Is this necessary?